# ifnull () over multiple column

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two  tables, and i have created left join query for them. 
Suppose they are Table A And Table B.

When i fire query  if Table B  contains key which is present in Table  A  then record are displays according to it.  if key not matches it displays null over all columns

if i have to replace null i use `ifnull` function of mysql , but there are much more column to apply `ifnull`, is there any way we can apply this function over all column at once ? means no need to apply on each individual columns

Comment: @gau123 Why use an update query?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you need to apply `IFNULL` to each column individually.

However, if you had a slightly different requirement, that is, to show the first non-null column from a number of columns, and show a default if they are all null, you could use the `COALESCE` function like so:

```
select coalesce(col1,col2,col3,0)
from tbl
```

The problem with this is that it will return a single column in the result, and not multiple columns corresponding to `col1`, `col2` and `col3`. Therefore, as long as you want to have multiple columns in your result set, you need to do the null handling on a per-column basis.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to use `IFNULL` on multiple columns at once, you have to do it on each column separately:

```
SELECT a.id, a.somecol, IFNULL(b.col1, 0) col1, IFNULL(b.col2, "") col2, ...
FROM Table1 AS a
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS b ON <some condition>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate your columns, such as:

```
SELECT CONCAT(col1, "|", col2, "|", col3, "|", col4) AS ConcatenatedString;
```

And then split the string with whichever split character you decide to use.. In this case a pipe "|"